# Heat equation with $x\in [0,+\infty[$ and non-homogeneous initial and boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, heat-equation

The IVBP that i need to solve is the follow:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t=au_{xx} & x>0,t>0,a\in\mathbb{R}^+\\
u(x,0)=B_0e^{-kx}\cos(kx) & x\geq 0,B_0\in\mathbb{R}^+,k\in\mathbb{R}^+\\
u(0,t)=B_0\cos(\omega t) & t\geq 0,B_0\in\mathbb{R}^+,\omega\in\mathbb{R}^+
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

How can i solve this using separation of variables method?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid Fourier Analysis?

Comment: Because i didn't study Fourier transform yet. But i can use separation of variables. Now i'm editing